# Stratified Sampling in python scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to divide my dataset into train and test sets using **stratified** sampling(**scikitlearn**).my approach is as follows :

1. I'am reading a CSV file and loading it using **pandas** readCSV.so ultimately i'am storing the loaded csv in a dataframe names "dataset"

   `dataset = pd.readCSV('CSV_NAME')`
2. Now I am applying stratified sampling as :

   `train,test = train_test_split(dataset,test_size=0.20,stratify=True)`

But it throwing the following **error** :

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(True, dtype=bool) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

So please suggest me the correct way of doing to it.

Answer (score 1):

'train_test_split' needs to know what the target variable is. Therefore, you should change your call to something like:

```
train,test = train_test_split(dataset[needed columns], dataset.target,test_size=0.20,stratify=True)
```

Comment: Hi Stergios , i need all columns in dataset and what does it dataset.target.Still i have modified it as :  train,test = train_test_split(dataset[target_cols],dataset.target,test_size=0.20,stratify=True)
 but it throwing  error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'

Comment: 'Target' is your target variable; the one you're trying to predict. You should change this to your actual column name. 'target_cols' should be the rest of the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, there is a missing single quote in your first line of code.

You could convert the pandas dataframe to a numpy array by the following

```
import numpy
dataset = pd.readCSV('CSV_NAME')
dataset = array(dataset)
```

like suggested in the second answer here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-python-pandas-go-along-with-scikit-learn-library-Has-anyone-doing-data-analysis-using-pandas-and-then-then-fit-models-using-scikit-learn

Or you could read the dataset into a numpy array directly.